# How do I make typescript work with promises?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, typescript, promise, bluebird

So, I am using typescript on a node/express/mongoose application and I am trying to have my code typecheck without errors.

I define this mongoose model:

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

const City = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

interface ICity extends mongoose.Document {
  name: string
}

export default mongoose.model<ICity>('City', City);
```

and this controller:

```
import * as Promise from 'bluebird';

import CityModel from '../models/city';

export type City = {
  name: string,
  id: string
};

export function getCityById(id : string) : Promise<City>{
  return CityModel.findById(id).lean().exec()
  .then((city) => {
    if (!city) {
      return Promise.reject('No Cities found with given ID');
    } else {
      return {
        name: city.name,
        id: String(city._id)
      };
    }
  });
}
```

The problem is that for some reason, typescript resolves my 'getCityById' function as returning a `Promise<{}>` rather than a `Promise<City>` as it should.

Failed attempts:

- I tried to wrap the return object in a `Promise.resolve`
- I tried to use `new Promise` and rely on mongoose's callback API as opposed to their promise API

Comment: Maybe because in one branch you return a `Promise` and in the other you return a `City` and when the compiler tries to infer the type the function returns the best it can do with these two is the empty object.

Comment: Nope, I tried to remove the branch where a promise is returned and I still get the same error

Comment: Furthermore, I tried wrapping the city in a promise... same error

Comment: Yeah, sorry, missed that part in your question. Have you tried `.then<City>(...)`?

Comment: Oh wow, it worked. Thanks! How come this worked?

Comment: If you look at the definition file you'll see that then `then` method has a generics signature. The compiler should have inferred the type without the need to explicitly write it, but it fails to do that, not sure why. In any case, by specifying the type you tell the compiler which type to include in the resulting `Promise`

Comment: Surely, `return Promise.reject(...)` is an anti-pattern. Does typescript not allow you to `throw` a `new Error()` at that point?

Answer (score 1):

> typescript resolves my 'getCityById' function as returning a Promise<{}> rather than a Promise as it should.

This is because of multiple return paths.

```
if (!city) {
      return Promise.reject('No Cities found with given ID');
    } else {
      return {
        name: city.name,
        id: String(city._id)
      };
    }
```

Specifically `Promise.reject` is untyped.

## Quick fix

Assert:

```
if (!city) {
      return Promise.reject('No Cities found with given ID') as Promise<any>;
    } else {
      return {
        name: city.name,
        id: String(city._id)
      };
    }
```